docker Container Sonarqube is not running in ec2

I tried to install sonarqube on ec2 as a container using the below commands, but it is getting exited and when I try to access it on the port <ec2-ip>:9000 it is not opening. How can I fix this issue?
docker pull sonarqube

docker run -d --name sonarqube-db -e POSTGRES_USER=sonar -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar -e POSTGRES_DB=sonarqube postgres:alpine

Run SonarQube
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 --link sonarqube-db:db -e SONAR_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonarqube -e SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar -e SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar sonarqube

I tried the same approach in my local, and the container is up andenter image description here running. Why am I facing this issue in ec2 instance of t2.micro?
docker logs is showing the error in the snapshot. how can I fix this?
